# How can I extract datetime in varchar from colon separated flat file?

Tags: sql-server

How can I split data using : as delimiter?

```
    12012040000:724243597:Abhishek:Mishra:male:Millburn, New Jersey: New Delhi, India: 
    Married: Accenture:
    11/9/2015 12:00:00 AM:india.delhi@gmail.com:12/15 <!(The given string)!>

BULK INSERT dbo.USA FROM 'F:\Torrent Downloads\USA\USA 01.txt'


WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ':',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    TABLOCK
)
```

I have created a table to insert

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USA](
        [phoneno] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [FBId] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [fname] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [lname] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [gender] [varchar](6) NULL,
        [state] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [city] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [mari_status] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [company] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [account_creation_date] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [emailid] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [dob] [varchar](100) NULL
       ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now how can I put all the data in all its places truncating properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *account_creation_date* part that has colon chars will confuse the `BULK INSERT` operation. That's why here is a different approach by using `OPENROWSET()` and handling the entire line as whole via T-SQL, and XML tokenization.

I saved your data as a *e:\Temp\Rupa.txt* file.

```
12012040000:724243597:Abhishek:Mishra:male:Millburn, New Jersey: New Delhi, India: Married: Accenture:11/9/2015 12:00:00 AM:india.delhi@gmail.com:12/15
12012040770:111243597:Rupa:Mishra:male:Millburn, New Jersey: New Delhi, India: Married: Accenture:11/9/2015 12:00:00 AM:india.delhi@gmail.com:08/10
```

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.USA;

CREATE TABLE dbo.USA(
        phoneno varchar(100) NULL,
        FBId varchar(100) NULL,
        fname varchar(500) NULL,
        lname varchar(500) NULL,
        gender varchar(6) NULL,
        state varchar(500) NULL,
        city varchar(500) NULL,
        mari_status varchar(100) NULL,
        company varchar(500) NULL,
        account_creation_date varchar(100) NULL,
        emailid varchar(500) NULL,
        dob varchar(100) NULL
);

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ':';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\Temp\Rupa.txt'
        , FORMATFILE = 'e:\Temp\Rupa.xml'  
        , ERRORFILE = 'e:\Temp\Rupa.err'
        , FIRSTROW = 1 -- real data starts on the 1st row
        , MAXERRORS = 100
        ) AS tbl
)
INSERT INTO dbo.USA
SELECT phoneno = c.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , FBId = c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , fname = c.value('(/root/r[3]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , lname = c.value('(/root/r[4]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , gender = c.value('(/root/r[5]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , state = c.value('(/root/r[6]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , city = c.value('(/root/r[7]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , mari_status = c.value('(/root/r[8]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , company = c.value('(/root/r[9]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , account_creation_date = c.value('(/root/r[10]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)') + @separator
        + c.value('(/root/r[11]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') + @separator
        + c.value('(/root/r[12]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)')
    , emailid = c.value('(/root/r[13]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    , dob = c.value('(/root/r[14]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(line, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c);

-- test
SELECT * FROM dbo.USA;
```

**FORMATFILE = 'e:\Temp\Rupa.xml'**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <RECORD>
      <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\r\n' MAX_LENGTH="2048" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
   </RECORD>
   <ROW>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="line" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
   </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

**Output**

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------+
|   phoneno   |   FBId    |  fname   | account_creation_date |        emailid        |  dob  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------+
| 12012040000 | 724243597 | Abhishek | 11/9/2015 12:00:00 AM | india.delhi@gmail.com | 12/15 |
| 12012040770 | 111243597 | Rupa     | 11/9/2015 12:00:00 AM | india.delhi@gmail.com | 08/10 |
+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution, I will check and mark as answer, can you tell me how can i transfer the xml to database

Comment: @Rupa'sDelights, I modified the answer. All you left to do is to copy it to SSMS, adjust three file paths like **'e:\Temp\Rupa.txt'**, etc. to match your environment, and run it. The answer loads XML into a database.

Comment: @Rupa'sDelights, (1) it seems you need to adjust permissions for that file system location.  (2) all file paths ( F:\...) are for the machine where SQL Server instance runs (On a server ?!). It is not for your local machine.

Comment: @Rupa'sDelights, please connect with me on LinkedIn

Comment: Sir I sent you the request in Linkedin

Comment: Query is executing forever and BULK INSERT executes faster. Please help